# 302 response GET request using .request() in testcafe

Tags: api, request, testcafe

My code is the following, Im attempting a very easy GET request:

```
  const response = await t.request({
  url:'https://mailsac.com/api/addresses/sometestuser@mailsac.com/messages',
  method: 'GET',
  rawResponse: true,
  headers: {'Mailsac-Key': 'key-to-the-api'}
  });
  console.log(response);
```

For which I get a 302, "found" response. Which means I'm getting redirected.

But it does work with `fetch()`. I can pull out a magic link from there:

```
  fetch('https://mailsac.com/api/addresses/sometestuser@mailsac.com/messages', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {'Mailsac-Key': 'key-to-the-api'}
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json =>  {
        const magicLink = json[0].links[0];
        console.log(magicLink);
         });
```

Am I doing something wrong? If I want to check the `response.body;` I get an awful buffer with no data in it.

PD: Is there a way to integrate fetch on my run? I don't seem to understand how can I use the data inside that .then() later during testcafe run.

I'm using the proxyless-mode, unsure if related.

Answer (score 2):

It's already fixed in [this PR](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/pull/7556) and will work in the next TestCafe version.

Comment: I've been so lucky with the timing for this fixes.